# Dependency conflicts of base in Haskell cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-sandbox

There comes up with a problem that cabal's `base` is conflicted with the dependency in `.cabal` file, it seems that my `base` version is too high, so is there a way to downgrade my `base` package version in the `cabal sandbox`.

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: decafc-0.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of decafc)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.11.1.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: decafc => base>=4.5
&& <=4.9)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0,
base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0,
base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0,
base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0,
base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0,
base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable
package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, decafc)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, decafc
Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unrstering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

There is another problem that when using `stack`, how to add some flags to the `alex` if running `stack build`, for example, the cabal instruction is `cabal install --alex-options="--ghc --template=\"$TOP/alex\""`. So how to let the `stack` do the same things?

Comment: `base` package is a part of the compiler, so you'd need to downgrade GHC itself. Or bump the required `base` version in `decafc` .cabal file.

Comment: Is there a solution for `cabal sandbox` to install a new `ghc` locally just like what `stack` do?

Comment: No. If you want to install a new ghc, you just install a new ghc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base` dependency indicates that it only works with versions between 4.5 and 4.9. That means the latest GHC you can use this package with is 8.0.1, since `base` ships with GHC and can't be upgraded. You could bump the dependency yourself, but you would likely have to fix things that don't work anymore due to changes in `base`, or you could install an older version of GHC.