# Could not resolve dependencies while installing libraries with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

Every effort of me trying to install a library using cabal on Window 10 resulted in the same error:

```hs
cabal install gtk
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: parconc-examples-0.4.8 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of parconc-examples)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.15.0.0/installed-4.15.0.0 (conflict: parconc-examples
=> base>=4.5 && <4.14)
[__1] skipping: base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0
(has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail:
excluded by constraint '>=4.5 && <4.14' from 'parconc-examples')
[__1] rejecting: base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0,
base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, parconc-examples)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, parconc-examples
```

It worked perfectly fine on Linux, but I have not found how to resolve the problem on Windows.

Comment: Another useful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939023/dependency-conflicts-of-base-in-haskell-cabal

Answer (score 10):

Your version of the `base` library is `4.15.0.0`. `base` is special in the sense that its version is [tied to your GHC version](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history), which seems to be GHC 9.0.1.

So, unlike with other libraries, cabal can't simply install a previous version of `base` when it's required by the `build-depends:` of some package.

`parconc-examples` has the following constraint on `base`: `>=4.5 && <4.14`. So version `4.15` is not accepted ("constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance").

One thing you could try is to pass the extra option [`--allow-newer=base`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html?highlight=allow-newer#cfg-field-allow-newer), like  `cabal install --allow-newer=base gtk`. This will relax the restriction.

But it isn't a panacea: `parconc-examples` (or other package required by `gtk`) might actually fail to build with `base == 4.15`, because it might use some aspect of `base == 4.14` that has changed in a non-backwards compatible way. Preventing such build failures is the purpose of bounds, after all.