# Installing a Haskell program like `hackage-cli`

Tags: haskell

I would to install this program

https://github.com/hackage-trustees/hackage-cli

What is the simple way to do so ?

If I try to build it locally with

```
> cabal --version 
cabal-install version 3.4.1.0 
compiled using version 3.4.1.0 of the Cabal library)
```

I get

```
 ❯ cabal v1-build
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: hackage-cli-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of hackage-cli)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.15.1.0/installed-4.15.1.0 (conflict: hackage-cli =>
base>=4.10.0.0 && <4.13)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, hackage-cli)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: hackage-cli, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring hackage-cli-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
Cabal >=2.4.1.0 && <2.5,
aeson >=1.4.2.0 && <2.1,
base >=4.10.0.0 && <4.13,
http-io-streams >=0.1.0.0 && <0.2,
io-streams >=1.5.0.1 && <1.6,
lens >=4.17 && <5.2,
netrc >=0.2.0.0 && <0.3,
optparse-applicative >=0.14 && <0.17,
process-extras >=0.7.4 && <0.8,
semigroups >=0.18.3 && <0.21,
stringsearch >=0.3.6 && <0.4,
tagsoup >=0.14 && <0.15,
tar >=0.5 && <0.6,
unordered-containers >=0.2.7 && <0.3,
zlib >=0.6.1 && <0.7
```

.

```
❯ cabal v2-build
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: hackage-cli-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of hackage-cli)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.15.1.0/installed-4.15.1.0 (conflict: hackage-cli =>
base>=4.10.0.0 && <4.13)
[__1] skipping: base-4.16.0.0, base-4.15.1.0, base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0,
base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0 (has the same
characteristics that caused the previous version to fail: excluded by
constraint '>=4.10.0.0 && <4.13' from 'hackage-cli')
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0,
base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0,
base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, hackage-cli)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, hackage-cli
```

.

```
❯ stack init
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- ./
- fixtures/

Multiple .cabal files found in directory /Users/nrolland/clones/hackage-cli/fixtures/:
- SVGFonts.2.cabal
- SVGFonts.0.cabal
- SVGFonts.1.cabal
- deepseq.1.cabal
- tree-diff.1.cabal
- semigroups.2.cabal
- semigroups.0.cabal
- tree-diff.0.cabal
- deepseq.0.cabal
- semigroups.1.cabal
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558825/could-not-resolve-dependencies-while-installing-libraries-with-cabal

Comment: `hackage-cli` isn't compatible with GHC-8.8 and newer yet. You can use GHC 8.2, 8.4 or 8.6 to install it. This is indicated by the `base` bounds in the error messages you posted.

Comment: @sjakobi looks like an answer. Why don't they target a well defined LTS for reproducible builds ??

Comment: I installed 8.6 and it is compiling. so it **might** produce some executable, provided nothing wrong happened anywhere among both all the dependencies, and also on the particular combination chosen today on my machine as a result of various update resulting in a new build plan... it's hard to imagine more mutable than that !

Comment: I guess the existing contributors mostly use cabal instead of stack. If you want to contribute a `stack.yaml`, it will very likely be accepted. I'm one of the maintainers.

Comment: I fail to build this project. If the contributors don't use the only tool out there to deliver reproducible builds, which is simple and has been around the years, I don't think they intend their tool to be used outside their circle. two reasons why I won't spend time on this

Comment: If you report the build failure on the issue tracker I'll take a look.

Comment: @sjakobi, there's a pull request filed on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

A solution is below.  Alternatively, you can clone from:

```
https://github.com/kabuhr/hackage-cli
```

to get a `stack build`-ready version.  Note that you may need to `apt install libbrotli-dev` or similar before `stack build`.

#### Long answer

Here, `stack init` is being fooled by some extra `.cabal` files in the `fixtures` subdirectory.  You can get around this by running `stack init --ignore-subdirs`.  This ends up selecting resolver `lts-14.27` but then fails because `http-io-streams` isn't in Stackage:

```
Selected resolver: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/
        commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/14/27.yaml
Resolver 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/
        stackage-snapshots/master/lts/14/27.yaml' does not have all
        the packages to match your requirements.
    http-io-streams not found
        - hackage-cli requires ^>=0.1.0.0
```

You can run:

```
stack init --resolver lts-14.27 --ignore-subdirs --omit-packages
```

to generate a `stack.yaml` anyway, and then add some `extra-deps` for `http-io-streams` and whatever it depends on.  After a little fiddling, I came up with the following `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-14.27

packages:
- .

extra-deps:
- http-io-streams-0.1.2.0
- brotli-streams-0.0.0.0
- brotli-0.0.0.0
```

One additional patch is needed because the code to support versions of `aeson` earlier than 2.0.0.0 is broken.  Apply the following patch:

```
diff --git a/src/IndexShaSum.hs b/src/IndexShaSum.hs
index 0296dff..bdfc4df 100644
--- a/src/IndexShaSum.hs
+++ b/src/IndexShaSum.hs
@@ -35,14 +35,15 @@ import           Data.Semigroup         ((<>))
 #if MIN_VERSION_aeson(2,0,0)
 import qualified Data.Aeson.Key         as Key
 import qualified Data.Aeson.KeyMap      as KeyMap
+type Key = J.Key
 
-keyToText :: J.Key -> Text
+keyToText :: Key -> Text
 keyToText = Key.toText
 #else
 import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict    as KeyMap
 type Key = Text
 
-keyToText :: J.Key -> Text
+keyToText :: Key -> Text
 keyToText = id
 #endif
 
@@ -139,7 +140,7 @@ decodePkgJsonFile bs = do
         go2 m = forM (KeyMap.toList m) $ \(k,v) -> do
             J.withObject ".targets{}" (go3 k) v
 
-        go3 :: J.Key -> J.Object -> J.Parser (ByteString, ByteString)
+        go3 :: Key -> J.Object -> J.Parser (ByteString, ByteString)
         go3 k o = do
             hashes <- o J..: "hashes"
             sh256 <- hashes J..: "sha256"
```

With that patch applied, and the `stack.yaml` in place, you should be able to run `stack build`.  If you get an error about building package `brotli`, you'll probably need development files for the `brotli` library installed (e.g., `apt install libbrotli-dev` on Debian flavors).

Comment: Great explanation. on a Mac, for the system libraries, one needs to `brew install openssl` then add the path provided by `echo $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib`  to the section in `stack.yaml`  `extra-lib-dirs:
  - /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib # $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib` and likewise for other system libraries

Comment: haskell has both stackage (which as far as I know, is pretty unique - ocaml uses the compiler version as an informal lts I think) and many nix aficionados. I don't understand why both are not used together and building is not best in class. many haskell project use no stackage and no nix. They are willingly bound to fail by design. Either I am missing something or this is crazy (with a remote possibility of both)